# Angular 5 how to preload and minify the styles.scss

Tags: angular, angular5

I am using Angular 5 in my web application and wants to preload the styles.scss file into the project. The project is having the angular-cli.json file also.

The rendered index.html file contains the tag like this :-

```
<link href="styles.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The angular-cli.json file looks like this :-

```
 "styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ],
```

I want to try adding the **rel="preload"** option to make the page loading faster and also to minify the styles.scss file.

Please suggest how to make these both changes.

Comment: angular already do this checkthis build result  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/malbarmawi/angular-lessons/gh-pages/styles.e01bd05a1de5ff826edf.css

Comment: how about minification of css file at the component level ?

Comment: You are right. It is inbuilt.